# Scrape page after its AJAX requests are complete

Tags: python, ajax, beautifulsoup

I am scraping:

```
http://www.wotif.com/hotel/View?hotel=W3830&page=1&adults=2&startDay=2014-11-08&region=1&descriptionSearch=true#property-reviews
```

using the following code:

```
hotel_page  = requests.get(hotel_url).text
hotel_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(hotel_page)
```

However, this does not include the [`Guest Review`](http://www.wotif.com/hotel/View?hotel=W3830&page=1&adults=2&startDay=2014-11-08&region=1&descriptionSearch=true#property-reviews) section, reason being that it is loaded by an AJAX call after the page is loaded.

**Question: how can I scrape the page only after all its AJAX calls are completed?**

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I have the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call this [URL](http://www.wotif.com/review/fragment?propertyId=W3830&limit=5) as well as make sure `X-Requested-With` is `XMLHttpRequest`

```
URL="http://www.wotif.com/review/fragment?propertyId=W3830&limit=5"

headers={"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest",
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"}

r=requests.get(URL,headers=headers)

#response here will be in json format
#Page source can be extracted using key `html'`
response=r.json()['html']
soup=BeautifulSoup(response)
reviews=soup.find(class_="review-score review-score-large").text
print reviews

Out[]:u'\n\n4.4\nOut of 5\n\n\n'

print reviews.strip()

Out[]:u'4.4\nOut of 5'
```

Comment: But this will load only `5` guest reviews each time ... And I have will have to put this in for loop to get all reviews

Comment: @Umair So what is the issue with that? You do it the same way. I answered your question - if you need more then please change your question accordingly and I will answer it

Comment: You scraped  the wrong URL ... see in my question ... I want to scrape that one after it has comleted the AJAX

Comment: @ Umair that is the way to scrape AJAX. When we use browser - they are well adopted to use javascript and/or to redirect to multiple urls and get the data. When using requests you need to swticth them manually or let python know the logic of switching to them. I didnt scrape the wrong url - that is the way it is to be scraped. I guess you need to learn more about AJAX requests. Please use Chrome's net tab to observe these

Answer (score -1):

It's much simpler. If you request the URL `http://www.wotif.com/review/fragment.json?propertyId=W3830&limit=100&bestThing=True` you get all the reviews in json-format.

The URL `http://www.wotif.com/review/fragment?propertyId=W3830&limit=100&` gives you reviews in html embedded in json. You have to look yourself, what fits your needs best.

Comment: If you visit 
`http://www.wotif.com/review/fragment.json?propertyId=W3830&limit=100&bestThing=True`
You will see the date of review and the scores of review too ... BUT IN THE JSON Response .. they are not available ...